# Given $f(x,y)=sin(x^2y)$, Prove that $Df(0,0)=0$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

Assume that $f(x,y)=sin(x^2y)$ is given.

a) Show that $f_x(0,0)=0$ and $f_y(0,0)=0$.

b) Then Prove that $f$ is differentiable on $(0,0)$ and $Df(0,0)=0$.

Note: I wrote the formula for the first part and solved it. The problem is the second part.  This is my try:
I claim that $Df(0,0)=0$. So, $L(h,k)=(0,0)$. Then i should prove that:

$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)} \frac{f((0,0)+(h,k))-f((0,0))-(0,0)}{|| (h,k) ||}= \lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{sin(h^2k)-sin(0)}{||(h,k)||}=\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{sin(h^2k)}{|| (h,k) ||}$

So, How can i prove that $\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{sin(h^2k)}{|| (h,k) ||}=0$ ?

Comment: The partial derivatives are continuous. That's enough to guarantee the total derivative exists.

Comment: $|\sin u|\le |u|.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{|sin(h^2k)|}{|| (h,k) ||}  \leq \frac{|sin(h^2k)|}{|h |} \leq \frac{|h^2k|}{|h |} = |h| |k|   $$

Answer (score 0):

from where you leave written $$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{sin(h^2k)}{|| (h,k) ||}=0$$
$$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{h^2k sin(h^2k)}{(h^2k) || (h,k) ||}=0$$
$$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{h^2k sin(h^2k)}{(h^2k) || (h,k) ||}=0$$and we know that $$\\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{sin(h^2k)}{(h^2k) }=0$$
hence we get $$\lim_{(h,k)\to(0,0)}\frac{h^2k }{|| (h,k) ||}=0$$
after that you can eaisly proove it
just we have to show itst limit is zero